# Execute a virsh command as another user in interactive setup script

Tags: sudo, root, su, libvirt, virsh

I am using a script to setup some Fedora machines and I can not execute a Virsh (cli tool for Libvirt) command as another user. The output given indicates that the command was successful but it fails silently. The script runs as root and I am trying to change to the uid 1000 (also called *user* in the system).

Here is the command that should be executed as *user*:

```
virsh define /home/user/vm.xml
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
sudo -u user bash -c 'virsh define /home/user/vm.xml'
su -c 'virsh define /home/user/vm.xml' user
su -s /bin/bash -c 'virsh define /home/user/vm.xml' -g user user
```

All of these commands return the following message:

```
Domain 'vm' defined from /home/user/vm.xml
```

This virtual machine, however, is not visible in virt-manager when executing the same command directly in the terminal as user, which appears in the GUI directly.
Hence, my assumption is that it fails silently.

What am I missing here?
Shouldn't `su -l` mimic a successful user login, change from root, and load everything needed to execute commands as the given user?

Comment: What is output from `sudo -u user virsh --connect=qemu:///session list`